# Trim string from beginning to substring c#

Tags: c#, string

I am having trouble cutting down my string. I have a windows form application that receives   incoming data. So far the examples I have found all use char to locate. I need to have it search for the entire  `"*S"` and not just one character of it.

I did  find a  way to get the index of the sting and trim from that point to the end `(sting.remove).` My problem is i need to trim the beginning. so a trim to index method would work but I haven't found how to do that.

What i have is a bunch of data like

```
"ok \r\n *S 38773 get 3042"
```

What I need to do is locate the `*S and remove everything from the beginning to the *S`. Because the return is not always the same I cant use replace or remove methods. I cant predict what will come before the *S and the remaining data is dynamic.

Any examples on how to essentially trim start to the "*S" would be wonderful. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
string huh = "ok \r\n *S 38773 get 3042";
string trimmed = huh.Substring(huh.IndexOf("*S"));
```

Answer (score 9):

```
s = s.Substring(s.IndexOf("*S"));
```

Comment: +1 - Note that you can leave off the "+ 2" if you want to keep the "*S" as part of the result.

Comment: Please update as Reed mentioned, if it will continue to get upvotes but doesn't do what the question asked :p